# Export a project in RDF

Tags: openrefine

Is it possible to export a project in RDF (XML/RDF, N3 or other serialisation)?
Use case :
I imported RDF/XML data in Openrefine, made changes to some values, and wanted to export the result in RDF/XML, in order to replace the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @pintoch that OpenRefine is not necessarily the right tool for that. Was there a specific reason that you used OpenRefine and did not edit the RDF directly? Turtle is the best serialization in case you simply want to do some basic changes. For more complex things you could use [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/) tooling and for example write some SPARQL queries that bulk-edit content in the RDF.

If you describe in more details what you were doing we might give some other tips. But if it had to be OpenRefine, the RDF extension he linked is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [RDF extension](https://github.com/stkenny/grefine-rdf-extension) for that.

I am not sure how easy it is to match the format of the RDF file you started from though. OpenRefine is primarily designed to work on tabular data so there might be better tools for this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you
I have no specific use case, but I will train some people to use Openrefine, and I wanted to know if it was the right tool to batch edit RDF files. Well, it seems it is not the case.

Comment: No problem! Note that you should rather add this as a comment on the answers.